# Add image to Report viewer with path from xml file

Tags: xml, reportviewer

I am creating a report with report viewer.

The data is from a xml file.

One of the fields of the xml file is the path to the image.

```
 <IMGMOD>C:\Projectos\2022\197\3D CAD 197\REPORTS\CP 02 - ARMARIO SHOWROOM - BASE\DADOS\Docs\IMAGES\MD22.3594.jpg</IMGMOD>
```

So in report viewer i'm using this field as the image source but it doesn't work.

[Image properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp7Oe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Image properties add "file:///" to the expression.

The final code is like:

```
="file:///"&Fields!IMGMOD.Value
```